# Getting last name from db django

Tags: android, python, django

I am new to django i made a webservice in django using tastypie. I send image from my android application and it is saved in required folder. I want to get the name of image that is sent my user to my api. I tried this code but i am getting the second last name from db. I want to get the last name of image which is just sent by the user because i have to do processing and send response back to user

This is my model

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image

class Foo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null=True, blank=True)
```

And this is my api.py

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.constants import ALL
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from models import Foo
from article import forms


class MultipartResource(object):
    def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
        if not format:
            format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
        if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            return request.POST
        if format.startswith('multipart'):
            data = request.POST.copy()
            data.update(request.FILES)
            return data
        return super(MultipartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)


class FooResource(MultipartResource,ModelResource):
    img = fields.FileField(attribute="img", null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'article'
        authorization = Authorization()

    obj=Foo.objects.latest('id')
    lastid=obj.pk
    imagename=Foo.objects.get(id=lastid)         
    print imagename
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is with the caveat that I have no idea what tastypie is and it may be doing something weird.

[latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) is meant to be used on dates, not integers. It gets the latest entry by the date field you specify. `id` is not a date field. Instead of `Foo.objects.latest('id')` you could try `Foo.objects.last()` which will probably work for you, but it isn't guaranteed.

The best way to solve this problem is to add a `DateField` or `DateTimeField` to your model that saves the time the image was created. You can use `auto_now_add` to make this automatic. So in your model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Note that `img` should not have `null=True`, as it is actually a CharField.

Then you can do:

```
obj = Foo.objects.latest('creation_date')
```